# Retrieve all the bookings that overlap with a given booking start and end time. Mysql - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am having a little trouble with the logic of this sql, I don't know why it's given me an error but the error is at line 4 "the start of the first AND". What I am trying to do is to check if the given start and end time are valid to book a room. I wanna show the user all the bookings that will overlap with the period he wanna book the room in.

```
select * from `bookings` 
where (
    `room_id` = 4 
       and (`starting_time` < 2022-11-16 23:07:55 
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-16 23:07:55
             and `starting_time` < 2022-11-17 00:07:55 
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-17 00:07:55) 
       or (`starting_time` < 2022-11-16 23:07:55 
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-16 23:07:55
             and `starting_time` < 2022-11-17 00:07:55 
             and `ending_time` < 2022-11-17 00:07:55)
       or ( `starting_time` > 2022-11-16 23:07:55 
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-16 23:07:55
             and `starting_time` < 2022-11-17 00:07:55 
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-17 00:07:55)
      )
```

```
 $bookings = Booking::where('room_id', $room_id)
            ->Where(function ($query) use ($times) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '<', $times[0])
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $times[0])
                    ->where('starting_time', '<', $times[1])
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $times[1]);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($times) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '<', $times[0])
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $times[0])
                    ->where('starting_time', '<', $times[1])
                    ->where('ending_time', '<', $times[1]);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($times) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '>', $times[0])
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $times[0])
                    ->where('starting_time', '<', $times[1])
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $times[1]);
            })
            ->get();
```

```
Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) 
{ 
  $table->bigIncrements('id'); 
  $table->datetime('starting_time'); 
  $table->datetime('ending_time')->nullable(); 
  $table->string('guest_name')->nullable(); 
  $table->string('guest_phone')->nullable(); 
  $table->longText('comments')->nullable(); 
  $table->timestamps(); $table->softDeletes(); 
});
 Schema::table('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('room_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('room_id', 'room_fk_7600582')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('team_id', 'team_fk_7547221')->references('id')->on('teams');
        });
```

Comment: no error message/code?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '23:07:55
             and `ending_time` > 2022-11-16 23:07:55
            ...' at line 4

Comment: That's what I am getting in sql and in laravel it just shows the same page without the booking records but also without errors.

Comment: oh put single quotes around your dates ' , like this:  '2022-11-16 23:07:55'

Comment: please share the Booking schema or migration

Comment: I put quotes and it worked but it ignored the room id condition and still showing nothing in laravel

Comment: room_id is not present in your schema

Comment: is there a bridge table?

Comment: Nope my bad I had an add-relations-to-table file. I updated the question with the scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get overlapping booking, you need to change your conditions (some are unnecessary and others are wrong)

I'm supposing that `$time[0]` is prior to `$time[1]`

```
$startingTime = $time[0];
$endingTime = $time[1];
$bookings = Booking::where('room_id', $room_id)
       ->where(function ($query) use ($startingTime , $endingTime) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($startingTime , $endingTime) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '>=', $startingTime)
                    ->where('ending_time', '<=', $endingTime);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startingTime) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '<=', $startingTime)
                    ->where('ending_time', '>', $startingTime);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($endingTime) {
                $query->where('starting_time', '<', $endingTime)
                    ->where('ending_time', '>=', $endingTime);
            });
       })
       ->get();
```

That should do it.

Comment: It still ignore the room_id condition and shows all the rooms within these given times. I echoed the room_id and it's already shown in the url so it does be passed to the function but not the condition

Comment: You need to move the 2nd Where() and the 2 orWheres into another Where(). If you want to use $startingTime and $endingTime in your closures you need to pass them to the use construct.

Comment: That worked, thank u all so much ^^

Comment: @HagarMaher fixed the errors

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @N69S answer but with the additional grouping around the three pairs of date criteria and the variables being passed to the closures -

```
$startingTime = $times[0];
$endingTime = $times[1];
$bookings = Booking::where('room_id', $room_id)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($startingTime, $endingTime) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($startingTime, $endingTime) {
                    $query->where('starting_time', '>=', $startingTime)
                        ->where('ending_time', '<=', $endingTime);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startingTime) {
                    $query->where('starting_time', '<=', $startingTime)
                        ->where('ending_time', '>', $startingTime);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($endingTime) {
                    $query->where('starting_time', '<', $endingTime)
                        ->where('ending_time', '>=', $endingTime);
                })
            })
            ->get();
```